# Smallest Rectangle to encapsulate two other rectangles

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to find the smallest rectangle that will encapsulate two other rectangles, say R1 and R2. Each rectangle is defined as follows.

```
  struct _Rectangle {
  int32_t swX; 
  int32_t swY;
  uint32_t Height;
  uint32_t Width; 
};
```

I have tried drawing it out and seeing the generic algorithm. However I have only gotten specific cases. For instance if R1 is in Quadrant 2 and R2 is in Quadrant 4 or R1 is in Quadrant 1 and R2 is in Quadrant 3.

I know there must be a simple way of assessing each of the 4 quantities the new rectangle requires.

Comment: Are your rectangles parallel to the coordinate system's axis?  If so, the bounding rectangle is defined simply by the minimum and maximum of the contained rectangles.

Comment: Yes the rectangles are always parallel to the axis i.e. either they are upright or on their side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy. Find the minimum and maximum values for x and y for all 8 points of both rectangles.

The bounding rectangle will be defined by the 4 points: (min_x, min_y), (min_x, max_y), (max_x, min_y), ( max_x, max_y)

With your representation you would do the following:

```
int32_t minX = r1.swX > r2.swX ? r2.swX : r1.swX;
int32_t minY = r1.swY > r2.swY ? r2.swY : r1.swY;
int32_t maxX = ( r1.swX + r1.Width ) > ( r2.swX + r2.Width ) ? 
               r2.swX + r2.Width : r1.swX + r1.Width;
int32_t maxY = ( r1.swY + r1.Height ) > ( r2.swY + r2.Height ) ? 
               r2.swY + r2.Height : r1.swY + r1.Height;

br.swX = minX;
br.swY = minY;
br.Width = maxX - minX;
br.Height = maxY - minY;
```

Comment: Right but I only need to define the southwest point of the rectangle. I would determine the width by adding minx and maxx and height by adding miny and maxy correct?

Comment: I updated with some code. You can transform it back to your representation. Getting height and width is done by subtracting min from max.

Answer (score 1):

You could

1. Convert your representation to 2 (x,y) pairs: (minx, miny) and (maxx, maxy).
2. Then take the max/min of the corresponding values (i.e. minimum on minx's, maximum of maxi's)
3. Convert back to your native representation

Comment: Could be more clear by what 2 (x,y) pairs you would representing with minx,miny and maxx, maxy

Comment: Minx = minimum x coordinate, maxx = maximum x coordinate